# how to convert image file in byte array angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am struggling converting image to byte array using client side script. I have to convert image to byte array, and pass this array to web service , so that the web services can save the image in  server. Any one please help me.

```js
$scope.file=function(user){
 //console.log("hhhhh",angular.toJson($scope.user));
 console.log(ContextService.object);
 $scope.users=ContextService.object;
 console.log($scope.user);
 
 //$scope.file=$scope.file;
 console.log($scope.user.file);
 var file=$scope.user.file;
 
  var bytes = [];   
           
           var fileReader = new FileReader();

           fileReader.onload = function (e) {    
               var naveen=fileReader.result;                
               for (var i = 0; i < naveen.length; ++i)
               {
                   bytes.push(naveen.charCodeAt(i));
                   bytes.push(0);
               }
             console.log("bytes",bytes);
      $scope.call(bytes);
       
           };
           fileReader.onerror = function(err) {
               console.log(err);
           };
           fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file); 
           
           $scope.call=function(bytes)
           {
            $scope.image=bytes;
            
           }
 

            $timeout(function() {
            console.log("vvvvv",$scope.image);   
         $scope.users.file=$scope.image;
            console.log("dsfdsfds",$scope.users);
            
          
          var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/signup";
             $http({
              method : "POST",
              url : url,
              data :angular.toJson($scope.users),
              headers : {

               "content-type" : "application/json",
               "Accept" : "application/json"
              }

             })

             .success(function(data) {
              console.log("Detail", angular.toJson(data));
              $state.go("login");
             });
            
               }, 3000);
```

Comment: var bytes = [];   

  var fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onload = function (e) {    
   var naveen=fileReader.result;                
   for (var i = 0; i < naveen.length; ++i)
   {
    bytes.push(naveen.charCodeAt(i));
    bytes.push(0);
   }
   console.log("bytes",bytes);
   $scope.call(bytes);

  };
  fileReader.onerror = function(err) {
   console.log(err);
  };
  fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file); 

  $scope.call=function(bytes)
  {
   $scope.image=bytes;

  }

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1323024/3690438